# Show that $x^n = a$ has at most one real positive real if $n$ is a positive integer

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Show that $x^n = a$ has at most one real positive real if $n$ is a positive integer.

I can solve this question by drawing graphs for different $n$. But how should I approach the problem if I want to solve it using calculus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^n-a$. By considering the derivative, show that $f$ is increasing on $[0 , \infty]$.

So, $f(x)=0$ has at most one solution.

Comment: Thanks! Can you solve this problem for me? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921226/show-that-the-equation-a-1e-alpha-1x-a-2e-alpha-2x-cdots-a-ne-al

Comment: @sourish: done!